# VS error in design time - Object of type 'ICustomType[]' cannot be converted to type 'ICustomType[]'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, propertygrid

I created a derived control from `PropertyGrid` and the following property causes troubles with the Visual Studio in Design time.

Note: There isn't any problem in runtime. It's only about designer and the problem get fixed if I remove manually the encoded value from the form's resource file.

The constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// Public constructor.
/// </summary>
public FilterablePropertyGrid()
{
    base.SelectedObjects = wrapper.ToArray();
}
```

The property code:

```
private List<ObjectWrapper> wrapper = new List<ObjectWrapper>();

/// <summary>
/// Overwride the PropertyGrid.SelectedObject property.
/// The object passed to the base PropertyGrid is the wrapper.
/// </summary>
public new List<ICustomType> SelectedObjects
{
    get
    {
        return wrapper.Any() ?
            base.SelectedObjects.Select(p => ((ObjectWrapper)p).SelectedObject).ToList() :
            new List<ICustomType>();
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null || value.Count == 0)
        {
            wrapper = new List<ObjectWrapper>();
            base.SelectedObjects = new object[] { };
        }
        else
        {
            wrapper = new List<ObjectWrapper>(value.Select(p => new ObjectWrapper(p)));
            // Link the wrapper to the parent PropertyGrid.
            base.SelectedObjects = wrapper.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The error:
[image]

I wonder if you could help me whats the problem is.

Comment: What's in the constructor of this class? Does the problematic code get called via the user or happen automatically when the class is instantiated? If automatically, that could be your problem and you could bypass the constructor if you're in design time. If that's the case, I can get you the code.

Comment: Is ICustomType a framework type, or your own custom type?

Comment: @MarcGravell: It's my own custom type

Comment: @BobHorn: I added the constructor code.. I don't think the problem is caused by it.

Comment: What happens if you comment that one line of code in the constructor? Do you still have the design-time issue?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is your own custom type (not a framework type), this error almost always means that you've declared the same interface in two different assemblies.

Check where this type is declared. It should only be in one assembly. Add references as necessary so that all places can access the type in a single assembly.

having the same code file compiled into two assemblies creates two different types that just happen to be called the same thing. They are not the same type and are not interchangeable.

Comment: In the code, there's no other type in another assembly in the same type. But I made the interface internal instead of public and seems the problem has been fixed. I still don't know what's going on.

Comment: @Homam that is really odd; unfortunately hard to repro here :(

Comment: @Mark Gravell. It's OK. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's a designer problem and the important thing for me is that I can use it now :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I went to the resx file, found the object of the type that causes the problem, and just deleted it.
Then I have assigned the property a value in run-time.
This way, the designer has nothing to complain about and you can safely use the derived control in a different assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in VS 2019, and eventually deleted the .vs folder. All was good after that.